# How to update the data on a screen in flutter while the changes are being made on a different screen?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm trying to update a screen in flutter when the data that is being shown on that screen is being updated on a different screen. I'm using firebase for the same.

Here's an example:
In my case, I have two pages, profile page and edit profile page. On the profile page, I have a field being displayed called username. On the edit profile page, users have the ability to change their username. Once the user changes their username, when they pop the screen, the new username should be displayed, but I'm not able to do that. The new username gets displayed only when I manually refresh the page.

How can I do that using flutter and firebase? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of describing your code, edit your question to show the [minimal code that can be used to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. I'll learn that!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing it and I haven't tested it, so It might not work but I hope you got the point. (Push a new screen with an user model, then call setstate once the async operations are done)

```
 TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewPage(model:model))).then((value) {
       setState(() {});});
         },
       child: const Text('button to new page'))
```